# Touchpad two finger scroll too fast. Synaptics not working

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, scrolling, xinput

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Lenovo Ideapad L340. The touchpad two-finger scrolling is too fast.

Tried Solutions like: `xinput --set-prop <id> 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' 8 8`

but getting the error: `property 'Synaptics Scrolling Distance' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`

Can anyone tell some easier way to do that. Graphical Interface would be helpful.
I don't know I installed too many unwanted packages reffering to many answers but it did not helped.

**EDIT: My Ubuntu Version:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Sorry, I have newly installed ubuntu so I was unaware of that, I actually dual-booted from windows to ubuntu. It's 20.04 release. Updated in question as well.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have the same issue in Ubuntu 22 running on Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th gen

Comment: @MohamedAlmahmood No, I can't still figure out, I tried every possible solution mentioned over the internet but the issue still persists. If you can't find some possible solution please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have IdeaPad and this problem too. Try to start Ubuntu with XORG (on loading screen tap to right down corner)
then (what is in parentheses does not need to be written to the terminal)

```
xinput (then find your touchpad)
xinput list-props id (id is touchpad)
```

then set up Scrolling Distance